# Angular JS service integration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I am new in angular js. In one of my application I want to integrate some data coming from different services to my view. Now what is best approach among the two:

1. Directly hit the service URLS as an ajax call from the angular `$http` service
2. Hit a servlet from angularjs controller and servlet will access the data from different services and combine the result in to a single JSON format and send back to angular controller.

Need suggestions in context of performance and configurability.

Comment: option 2 is the way to do it..

Comment: I would go with option 1

Answer (score 0):

Second one is better.
Reason:- Lesser the handshake with server better is the performance for server otherwise server will going to handle multiple events and respond them accordingly.